# Can you report on time payments on private loan?

Tags: loans, credit

We have a contractual loan (one with a contract, not a handshake) from an family member who bought our student loans. We pay regularly just like any other loan and we pay a small amount of interest (whatever the minimum was to avoid calling it a gift).

Is there any way to get our awesome payment history to show up in our Credit report? Not that we need it, but it's always nice to get "credit" for your on-time payments.

Comment: For obvious reasons, it is _not you_ but the _lender_ who gets to report on-time payments, and as Nate Eldredge's answer points out, it is unlikely that your lender has multiple accounts on which he/she reports timely (or untimely) payments. Be glad for what you have; a kindly family member who has generously paid off your student loans for you and is collecting the amount from you in easy installments at a very low interest rate.

Comment: I'm very grateful for it, this was purely out of curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so.

I found [TransUnion's page on data reporting](http://www.transunion.com/corporate/business/datareporting/gettingstarted/reporting-requirements.page): information for those organizations ("data providers") that report their accounts receivable data to TransUnion.  It explains the steps needed for becoming a data provider.  It's a [rather involved process](http://www.transunion.com/corporate/business/datareporting/gettingstarted/credentialing-req.page), but the most obvious deal-breaker in your case is that a data provider has to have at least 100 accounts.  Your family member evidently has only 1.

I couldn't find similar information for the other two major US credit reporting agencies (Experian and Equifax) but I am inclined to think it is probably similar.

Comment: Sweet, I wouldn't have known where and what to Google.